# Displaying multiple OpenCV VideoCapture objects in QT

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm capturing webcam streams from two raspberry pis and I'm trying to carry out some image processing on both streams. I have two Qlabels I'm trying to use to display the images from the pis. However, whilst one stream displays in real time, the other has a 4-5 second delay. The same result occurs if I try to display one stream on both Qlabel objects. Is this a threading issue? Can you guys please help out?

```
VideoCapture capWebcam;
VideoCapture EyeintheSky;
Mat matEyeInTheSky;
QImage qimgEyeInTheSky;
Mat matOriginal;
QImage qimgOriginal;

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
      ui->setupUi(this);

   capWebcam.open("http://192.168.0.102:8080/?action=stream?dummy=param.mjpg"); //from MJPG STreamer image processing

  EyeintheSky.open("http://192.168.0.100:8080/?action=stream?dummy=param.mjpg");

   if (capWebcam.isOpened() == false) {
      return;
      }

   if(EyeintheSky.isOpened() == false) {
    return;
     }
}

void MainWindow::processFrameAndUpdateGUI() {

capWebcam.read(matOriginal);
EyeintheSky.read(matEyeInTheSky);

if(matOriginal.empty() == true) {
    qDebug() << "Empty Picture";
    return;
}
else {
   //  start of visual processing

    // Output Tri Track images to screen
    // map QImage to QLabel
    cvtColor(matOriginal,matOriginal,COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    QImage qimgOriginal((uchar*)matOriginal.data,matOriginal.cols,matOriginal.rows, matOriginal.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->lblInputImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));

    // Output Eye in the Sky to screen
    // map QImage to QLabel
    cvtColor(matEyeInTheSky, matEyeInTheSky, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    QImage qimgEyeInTheSky((uchar*)matEyeInTheSky.data, matEyeInTheSky.cols, matEyeInTheSky.rows, matEyeInTheSky.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->sky_input->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgEyeInTheSky));

    // Process IK code.

     }

 }
```

Comment: Rendering via label isn't exactly efficient. Also the image to pixmap conversion can be very expensive (depends on the platform). OpenCV Qt integration doesn't come with a class to display a stream? However, instead of guessing where the bottleneck is, I'd consult a profiler.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, not to the best of my knowledge. Searching online, the common way seems to be converting a frame to a QImage and then displaying in a label. Sorry for the naivety, but whaty do you mean by "consulting a profiler"

Comment: Use a performance profiling tool to investigate where the bottleneck is.